# Why does this commented out MSpec Behavior show up in the ReSharper test runner?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, bdd, behavior, mspec

MSpec gurus, why doesn't this work?

```
public class with_command_line_args {
    protected const string ValidFilename = "ValidFilename.txt";
    protected const string InvalidFilename = "Invalid:Filename";
    protected static  string[] Args;
    protected static Exception Exception;
}

[Behaviors]
public class InvalidCommandlineArgsBehaviours
{
    protected static Exception Exception;
    It should_throw= () => Exception.ShouldNotBeNull();
    //It should_not_store_any_filename;
}

[Subject(typeof(Program), "Invalid command line parameter")]
public class when_invoked_with_no_parameters : with_command_line_args
{
    Establish context = () => Args = new string[] {};
    Because of = () => Exception = Catch.Exception(() => Program.ProcessCommandLineArgs(Args));
    Behaves_like<InvalidCommandlineArgsBehaviours> invalid_args;
}
```

When i run this in ReSharper, the specification shows up but doesn't execute (I can't debug it either):
[image: ReSharper Unit Test Runner output]
Curiously, the commented-out specification shows up in the ReSharper output. Eh? Clearly I'm not doing something right, please enlighten me!

Answer (score 1):

Ah, this must have been a wierd ReSharper thing. After quitting from Visual Studio and re-running the context, it works as expected.
[image: ReSharper test Runner output]

Answer (score 0):

This is a constant problem for me. Sometimes restarting Visual Studio resolves it. Sometimes renaming the behaviour. Sometimes just commenting out the tests in the behaviour and then re-enabling them one by one!
I've tried upgrading the Machine.Specifications ReSharper plug-in to no avail.

Right now I have one behaviour that I can't get to reliably run in the R# test runner no matter what I try...

I'd really appreciate any help offered!

ReSharper 6.1.1000.82
Machine.Specifications 0.5.6
Visual Studio 2010